# rebar cannot generate release because of gserialver.1.gz

Tags: erlang, debian, rebar

When I run `rebar generate` to generate a node using reltool, it fails with this error message:

```
ERROR: Unable to generate spec: read file info /usr/lib/erlang/man/man1/gserialver.1.gz failed
```

Why does that happen, and what can I do about it?

I'm running Debian squeeze (6.0.6), if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rebar prints `Unable to generate spec` when it gets an error message from reltool; the rest of the message comes directly from reltool.  In this case, reltool is trying to get file info for various files in the Erlang directory, but fails because `gserialver.1.gz` is a dangling symlink.

You might wonder why `gserialver.1.gz` is installed under `/usr/lib/erlang`. It actually isn't, but Debian creates `/usr/lib/erlang/man` as a symlink to `/usr/share/man`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/erlang/man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 15 12:19 /usr/lib/erlang/man -> ../../share/man
```

So the real culprit is `/usr/share/man/man1/gserialver.1.gz`, which is installed by the package `gcj-jre-headless`.  There is [a bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576298) about that which claims that this has been fixed; however if that's not the case on your box, here is a command that will move the file out of the way and make rebar happy:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /var/gserialver.1.gz --rename /usr/share/man/man1/gserialver.1.gz
```